Django/NGINX - CSRF verification failed in production on a 3g-enabled device
My django app works perfectly fine on other devices with 4G connectivity.
Trying to sign up or login on a device with only 3G capability throws the CSRF verification failed error. Even using a Wi-Fi network fails.
Any idea why that is?
I'm also using Cloudflare to configure/manage the domain name server. Thanks.
I already looked through the settings file (mostly following the docs) but don't wanna to break anything that's already working.
Here's my NGINX config:
upstream app_server {
   server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    # add here the ip address of your server
    # or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
    server_name jovimifah.com www.jovimifah.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    access_log /home/vickerdent/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/vickerdent/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/vickerdent/shop-central;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}

Also, CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE and SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE are True.

When a 3G device tries to connect, does the device use http instead of https?

I've gotten CSRF errors in the past that were caused by faulty http/https configurations.

@LordElrond it's always https. Plus SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT is on, as well as the SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER set to ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")

Can you post the HTTP packets for both a successful request (from a 4G device) and a failed request (from a 3G device)?  Comparing them might give answers.
